# Dynamically modify the content in \tablehead

Tags: tables

I have a pretty simple LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[us,12hr]{datetime}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{0.5pt}
\chead{\textbf{\huge{Hello}}}
\lhead{\textbf{Left}}
\rhead{\textbf{Right}}
\rfoot{\today \hspace{0.5pt} \currenttime}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{Lower Left}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\newcommand{\SpecialText}{Hello\ldots}
\newcommand{\testIt}{The value of \texttt{SpecialText} is : "\SpecialText''.}  
\begin{document}
\tablehead
{
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\textbf{Gross Volume}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\textbf{Net Volume}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{12mm}}{\textbf{Level}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\textbf{Temperature}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Ullage}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{42mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Last Updated}}}\\

& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Gallons}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Gallons}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{12mm}}{\textbf{inches}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Farenheit}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Gallons}}} & \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\testIt}\\\\
}

\begin{supertabular}{p{35mm}*{6}{r}}
\renewcommand{\SpecialText}{New Text\textit{was}\ldots} 
\\ \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {Set 1}}\\\\
\textbf{Subset 1} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Red}\\
Element 1& \multicolumn{6}{l}{(Disjoint)}\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Results}} & 3797.08 & 3780.49 & 38.85 & 66.21 & 5721.31 & 4/8/2012 9:00:21AM \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{State}} & 7.24 & & 0.54 & & & \\\\ 
\toprule[2pt]\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to dynamically change the content on the `\tablehead`, so that at the beginning of each page the text is different. I tried `\renewcommand` but it did not work.

Any help will be great.

---

In the following example, the article has been expanded to the second page. The heading remains the same, however the ***renew command*** is ignored, since on the second page, the upper right text should be changed from:

The Value of SpecialText is: "Original Text".

to:

The Value of SpecialText is: "New Text".

Any comments are welcome.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[us,12hr]{datetime} 
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\setlength\headheight{0.5pt} 
\chead{\textbf{\huge{Hello}}} 
\lhead{\textbf{Left}} 
\rhead{\textbf{Right}} 
\rfoot{\today \hspace{0.5pt} \currenttime} 
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}} 
\lfoot{Lower Left}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}  
\usepackage{supertabular} 
\newcommand{\SpecialText}{Original Text} 
\newcommand{\testIt}{The value of \texttt{SpecialText} is : "\SpecialText''.}   \begin{document} 
\tablehead 
{ 
\toprule & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{17mm}}{\textbf{Column 1}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{17mm}}{\textbf{Column 2}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{17mm}}{\textbf{Column 3}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{17mm}}{\textbf{Column 4}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{17mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Column 5}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{17mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Column 6}}}\\  
& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Column 1}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\textbf{Column 2}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{12mm}}{\textbf{Column 3}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\textbf{SubColumn 4}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\centering{\textbf{SubColumn 5}}} & \\ 
\toprule 
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\testIt}\\\\ 
}  
\begin{supertabular}{p{35mm}*{6}{r}} 
\renewcommand{\SpecialText}{New Text}
\\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {Set 1}}\\\\ 
\textbf{Subset 1} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Red}\\ 
Element 1 & \multicolumn{6}{l}{(Disjoint)}\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Results}} & 3797.08 & 3780.49 & 38.85 & 66.21 & 5721.31 & 4/8/2012 9:00:21AM \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{State}} & 7.24 & & 0.54 & & & \\\\  
\\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {Set 1}}\\\\ 
\textbf{Subset 1} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Red}\\ 
Element 1 & \multicolumn{6}{l}{(Disjoint)}\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Results}} & 3797.08 & 3780.49 & 38.85 & 66.21 & 5721.31 & 4/8/2012 9:00:21AM \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{State}} & 7.24 & & 0.54 & & & \\\\  
\\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {Set 1}}\\\\ 
\textbf{Subset 1} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Red}\\ 
Element 1 & \multicolumn{6}{l}{(Disjoint)}\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Results}} & 3797.08 & 3780.49 & 38.85 & 66.21 & 5721.31 & 4/8/2012 9:00:21AM \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{State}} & 7.24 & & 0.54 & & & \\\\
\\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {Set 1}}\\\\ 
\textbf{Subset 1} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Red}\\ 
Element 1 & \multicolumn{6}{l}{(Disjoint)}\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Results}} & 3797.08 & 3780.49 & 38.85 & 66.21 & 5721.31 & 4/8/2012 9:00:21AM \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{State}} & 7.24 & & 0.54 & & & \\\\  
\\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {Set 1}}\\\\ 
\textbf{Subset 1} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Red}\\ 
Element 1 & \multicolumn{6}{l}{(Disjoint)}\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Results}} & 3797.08 & 3780.49 & 38.85 & 66.21 & 5721.31 & 4/8/2012 9:00:21AM \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{State}} & 7.24 & & 0.54 & & & \\\\  
\\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {Set 1}}\\\\ 
\textbf{Subset 1} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Red}\\ 
Element 1 & \multicolumn{6}{l}{(Disjoint)}\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Results}} & 3797.08 & 3780.49 & 38.85 & 66.21 & 5721.31 & 4/8/2012 9:00:21AM \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{State}} & 7.24 & & 0.54 & & & \\\\  
\\ 
\renewcommand{\SpecialText}{New Text}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {Set 1}}\\\\ 
\textbf{Subset 1} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Red}\\ 
Element 1 & \multicolumn{6}{l}{(Disjoint)}\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Results}} & 3797.08 & 3780.49 & 38.85 & 66.21 & 5721.31 & 4/8/2012 9:00:21AM \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{State}} & 7.24 & & 0.54 & & & \\\\   
\toprule[2pt]\\ 
\end{supertabular} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an implicit grouping level in table cells, thus the redefinition gets lost after the cell is processed, where the redefinition occurs.

```
\gdef\SpecialText{New text}
```

makes a global (re)definition of `\SpecialText` and the `supertabular` uses this value in the head of the next page, because the head and foot are stored in macros.

BTW: This is a difference to package `longtable`. Table heads and foots are static and stored in boxes there.

### Example for sub-totals/cell catching

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\CatchCell{%
  \long\def\CatchCell#1\ignorespaces#2\unskip{%
    \def\CatchCell@obj{#2}%
    \trim@spaces@in\CatchCell@obj
    \expandafter\@CatchCell\expandafter{\CatchCell@obj}{#1}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\@CatchCell}[2]{%
  #2{#1}%
}
\@ifdefinable\CatchLastCell{%
  \long\def\CatchLastCell#1\ignorespaces#2\\{%
    \def\CatchCell@obj{#2}%
    \trim@spaces@in\CatchCell@obj
    \expandafter\@CatchCell\expandafter{\CatchCell@obj}{#1}\\%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textheight}{5\baselineskip}% for testing

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\mysum}{0}
\newcommand*{\entry}[1]{%
  #1\xdef\mysum{\the\numexpr\mysum+#1\relax}%
}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{%
  Previous sum: & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\mysum}\\
  \hline
}
\tabletail{%
  \hline
  Sum:& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\mysum}\\
}
\begin{supertabular}{l>{\CatchLastCell\entry}l}
a & 1 \\
b & 2 \\
c & 3 \\
d & 4 \\
e & 5 \\
f & 6 \\
g & 7 \\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- Cells except in the last column can be catched by `\CatchCell`. It takes an argument for a macro that can do something with the cell's content.
- The last column depends on the token that is used to finish the table row.
  In this example `\\` is used and `\CatchLastCell` must be used instead of `\CatchCell`.
- Care is needed for the head and tail part of the table. In this case, the command `\entry`, that adds the number to the sum, must not be repeated. Therefore `\multicolumn` is needed to overwrite the column specification.
- More serious calculations (financial data) can be done with package `fp`.

Comment: So you know that. Hm. Did you ever think about a package to calculate and print a sub-total of a certain column in the last row at the bottom of the page of a multipage tabular?

Comment: @KeksDose Example added.

Comment: Incredible. But I tend to be impertinent: Could you add a column definition: »all entries in this columns are numbers«, to get rid of the `\entry` command inside the tabular? Maybe something like `>{\Entry}l`! I'll pay your beer and meal at the next "Stammtisch" in KA, anyway . . .

Comment: Thank you for your comment Heiko. I ran your latex with more values and could not see the effect of the ***\CatchCell*** Would you please provide more description?

Comment: @KeksDose Problem solved (forgotten `\multicolumn` in table head and tail). Thus the example now combines sub-totals and cell catching. I hope, your offer for the next "Stammtisch" stands.